# Eliminate a row which repeat same values vise versa in two columns like Col A = 1 ,Col B = 2 then next row Col A = 2 ,Col B = 1

Tags: sql-server

[image]

from the above table I need records having (F_ID 101,302,both 599 and 444) excluding 201. The query should eliminate values which interchange and form another row. Like S_ID 201 belongs to F_ID 101 which is repeating again in the next row with vise versa ID's.

Desired result set.

[image]

Can anyone help me get a solution for this issue ?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to delete these records one-time, make a self-join query shoud do.

```
-- Tested for PostgreSQL Server
-- Check before delete.
select * from tbl A join tbl B on A.S_ID = B.F_ID and A.F_ID = B.S_ID and A.id > B.id;
-- Delete on PostgreSQL.
delete from tbl A using tbl B where A.S_ID = B.F_ID and A.F_ID = B.S_ID and A.id > B.id;

-- SQL-Server has a similar syntax.
delete A from tbl A, tbl B where A.S_ID = B.F_ID and A.F_ID = B.S_ID and A.id > B.id;
```

Query engine will make a Sort + MergeJoin plan, so it's fast on large tables.

Comment: Eleven Z thanks a lot for your solution !!